# C# conditional statements

Tags: c#

Can you guys point out what's wrong with this code?

What I want is, if someone answers as earth, to get you're right and if not you're wrong.

```
Console.WriteLine("What planet do we live on");

string name = Console.ReadLine();

if (name =earth)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes, you're right");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're wrong");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: what do you wish to know from this ?????

Comment: We tried to guess what your exact question is. But please include *error details* in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Notice the `^` sign in the code below:

```
Console.WriteLine("What planet do we live on");

string name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(name == "earth" ? "Yes, you're right" : "You are wrong");
                       ^^ ^     ^
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

you condition is incorrect. it should be

```
if (name == "earth"){ }
```

the values should also be quoted to avoid compiler error.

Comment: thank you mate. I wasn't using double quotes to the string.

Comment: @scylla - you also used a single `=` (assignement) instead of `==` (comparison).

Comment: you're welcome `:D` if you have multiple conditions, `IF` statement or `Switch` could be more effective than ternary operator like demonstrated by Hossein.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name == "earh")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes, you're right");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You're wrong");
}
```

You used `=` instead `==`.

You should compare to `"earth"` (`String`) and not earh

Answer (score 1):

`==` is the *equality comparision operator*, whereas `=` is an *assignment* in C#. Therefore you have to use `==` as others pointed out:

```
if(planet == earth) {
}
```

Using `=` would assign `earth` to `planet` and return `earth` rather than *comparing* and returning a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name == "earth")
{ 
}
```

When you check condition, == should be there in if.

If there is single = then it simply asigns the value.